# Python scraping more than 1 page and getting rid of duplicates

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Currently stuck my program isn't scraping past the first page and gives me repeating results when printing out to excel. I'm wondering how to fix this I was looking at the URL, but stuck on why I keep getting repeating results rather than just one result for each job posting.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

col = ['Name','Company','City','Ratings','Summary','Date']
indeed = pd.DataFrame(columns = col)`

for page in range(0,5):
    url = "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Analyst&l=92840&radius=150&start=10"
    P_url = requests.get(url)
    P_html = P_url.text
    P_soup = Soup(P_html, 'html.parser')
    containers = P_soup.findAll("div", {"data-tn-component": "organicJob"})
    #print(len(containers))
    #print(Soup.prettify(containers[0]))
    container = containers[0]
    for container in containers:
        Name = container.findAll("a", {"class": "jobtitle turnstileLink"})
        if len(Name) !=0:
            name = Name[0].text.strip()
        else:
            name = "NaN"
    
    Company = container.findAll("span", {"class":"company"})
    if len(Company) !=0:
        comp = Company[0].text.strip()
    else:
        comp = "NaN"
    
    City = container.findAll('span', {"class":"location accessible-contrast-color-location"})
    if len(City) !=0:
        city = City[0].text.strip()
    else:
        city = "NaN"
        
    ratings = container.findAll("span", {"class":"ratingDisplay"})
    if len(ratings) !=0:
        rat = ratings[0].text.strip()
    else:
        rat = "NaN"
        
    Summ = container.findAll("div", {"class":"summary"})
    if len(Summ) !=0:
        summ = Summ[0].text.strip()
    else:
        summ = "NaN"
        
    date = container.findAll('span', {"class":"date"})
    if len(date) !=0:
        dat = date[0].text.strip()
    else:
        dat = "NaN"
        
    data = pd.DataFrame([[name, comp, city, rat, summ, dat]])
    data.columns = col
    indeed = indeed.append(data, ignore_index = True)
    
P_url = requests.get(url)
P_url.text
    
print(indeed)
indeed.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: the formatting of your url in the loop is not good if the point is to change the page. do a `print(url)` to see what is the url you request at each loop. And to solve it, I believe you want `url = urls + f'&start={page*10}'`

Comment: Okay so I have a better url now that's doing what I want however I keep getting repeating outputs at the very end. How can I get unique data from each company in my output rather than repeating data.

Comment: `Name            Company        City Ratings  \`
`0  Purchasing Analyst, Body  Rivian Automotive  Irvine, CA     NaN   `
`1  Purchasing Analyst, Body  Rivian Automotive  Irvine, CA     NaN   `
`2  Purchasing Analyst, Body  Rivian Automotive  Irvine, CA     NaN`   
`3  Purchasing Analyst, Body  Rivian Automotive  Irvine, CA     NaN `  
`4  Purchasing Analyst, Body  Rivian Automotive  Irvine, CA     NaN`

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're not updating your `url` variable and you're not iterating over the `containers` properly. `Company`, `City`, etc are all out of the `containers` loop (check indentation).

As for the `url`, you probably want to do something like:

```
url = "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Analyst&l=92840&radius=150&start={}"

for page in range(0, 5):
    P_url = requests.get(url.format(10*page))
    ...
```

This should work as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

col = ['Name', 'Company', 'City', 'Ratings', 'Summary', 'Date']
indeed = pd.DataFrame(columns=col)
url = "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Analyst&l=92840&radius=150&start={}"

for page in range(0, 5):
    P_url = requests.get(url.format(10*page))
    P_html = P_url.text
    P_soup = Soup(P_html, 'html.parser')
    containers = P_soup.findAll("div", {"data-tn-component": "organicJob"})

    for container in containers:
        Name = container.find("a", {"class": "jobtitle turnstileLink"})
        if len(Name) != 0:
            name = Name.text.strip()
        else:
            name = "NaN"

        Company = container.findAll("span", {"class": "company"})
        if len(Company) != 0:
            comp = Company[0].text.strip()
        else:
            comp = "NaN"

        City = container.findAll('span', {"class": "location accessible-contrast-color-location"})
        if len(City) != 0:
            city = City[0].text.strip()
        else:
            city = "NaN"

        ratings = container.findAll("span", {"class": "ratingDisplay"})
        if len(ratings) != 0:
            rat = ratings[0].text.strip()
        else:
            rat = "NaN"

        Summ = container.findAll("div", {"class": "summary"})
        if len(Summ) != 0:
            summ = Summ[0].text.strip()
        else:
            summ = "NaN"

        date = container.findAll('span', {"class": "date"})
        if len(date) != 0:
            dat = date[0].text.strip()
        else:
            dat = "NaN"

        data = pd.DataFrame([[name, comp, city, rat, summ, dat]])
        data.columns = col
        indeed = indeed.append(data, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Good catch. To even improve more the code, create `data` and use `append` on a dataframe at each iteration will be slow if the number of items grows. One should better `append` in a list and create the dataframe after the loops :) and good answer btw